# Run Update Query with Agent Job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Agent job that is set to run the following query.  Unfortunately either on a schedule or manually started the job fails, but does not leave any data in the error logs.

There is a single step that needs to run the following query:

```
UPDATE TB1
SET TB1.STATUS = 'Complete'

FROM    
  Table1.dbo.A_P as TB1
  INNER JOIN [LS1].DB1.dbo.Detail AS CD ON CD.ID = TB1.ID
  JOIN [LS1].Header AS Header ON Header.ID = TB1.ID

WHERE 
TB1.STATUS='approved'
AND Header.Status='C';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of database is this (vendor)?

Comment: The table names look strange; are you sure they are correct?  What DBMS is this?

Comment: Does the query run successfully on its own?

Comment: The query does work on its own.  I change the table names for the means of this post.

Comment: @user1916730 right click on the job -> view history and find the error. what does this error say?

Comment: Are you saying that you see a red cross against the SQL Agent job but there is no information explaining why? So when you right click the job and 'View History' it is blank? Does the query on this page give you any info? http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1752/analyzing-sql-agent-job-and-job-step-history-in-sql-server/

Comment: This gave me what I needed.  I was looking in the wrong location for the job logging.  The issue was caused by how the Linked server was created and the account that the agent was configured under.  Thank you for pointing out the Job History; I feel like quite the newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gave me what I needed. I was looking in the wrong location for the job logging. The issue was caused by how the Linked server was created and the account that the agent was configured under. Thank you for pointing out the Job History; I feel like quite the newbie. – Ratoka